# Maps: is lat/lgn inside a rectangle

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Assume a rectangle defined by south-west lat/lgn (a,b) and north-east lat/lng (c,d) coordinates:

```
           c,d
|-----------|
|           |
|           |
|           |
|-----------|
a,b
```

How do I determine if another pair of coordinates x,y are within that rectangle? Is this correct:

```
a < x < c AND b < y < d  <-- if true, it means x,y are in the rectangle???
```

I'm using Google Maps API and am getting these lat/lng values from it. I just need to know if x,y are indeed inside the rectangle.

Comment: If lat/long, it's not really a rectangle, especially as you get closer to the poles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a `LatLngBounds` from the southwest and northeast coords, then call the `contains` method passing in the LatLng to check.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: Oh, I wanted to do the math myself and not rely on the API

Comment: I think that would be very tricky, especially if the rectangle crosses the equator or the prime meridian.

Comment: The equator doesn't matter.  The poles matter, as does the international date line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  One way to code this is

```
if (x < a) return false;
if (x > c) return false;
if (y < b) return false;
if (y > d) return false;
return true;
```

Note that my way considers a point to be "in" the rectangle if it's exactly on the border as well.  You may or may not consider that true.

Comment: This will work for any rectangle plotted on any place in the world, right? I'm just not so sure if lat/lgn is plotted like a normal graph. I assume it is, though. Not sure if it's right.

Comment: Well, the concept of "rectangle" gets a little wierd near the poles, because if your top latitude is 90 or -90, the "rectangle" actually becomes a triangle and depending on what you're doing, any point at 90 or -90 is "inside" the shape even if the longitudes don't match.  Again, it depends a lot on whether you consider the borders to be "in".

Comment: Another thing to be wary of is rectangles that you intend to span the International Date Line (longitude +180 or -180).  There is no easy way to make those work - I tend to make two rectangles, one in the positive longitudes and one in the negative longitudes just to make things easier and unambiguous.