# Calculating geospatial bounding box without map data

Tags: java, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm that would let me find an enclosing bounding box for a lat/long without using map data. Essentially I want to be able to define grids for the planar world map given a set size and then plot which grid a lat/long falls in.

Does anyone know of previous work that might have been done in this? Are there standard ways of doing this over home grown solutions where I create a hash map (or the like) of my own bounding boxes for the world and do lookups etc.

I dont want to utilize actual cartography for this. Just looking for some math that would return a fixed bounding box for all the lat/longs that fall under it

Thanks for your help!

Comment: similar (but not exactly the same) to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957994/maps-is-lat-lgn-inside-a-rectangle

Answer (score -1):

I guess you mean that you want to do something like cover the surface of the Earth with squares (or rectangles) of a fixed size, perhaps 100km square, and figure out a way of mapping from any (lat,long) coordinate pair to the square in which it sits ?  Well, forget about that, it can't be done, there is simply no way to cover the surface of a sphere (ignore the slight non-sphericity of the Earth for this discussion) with squares of the same size.

You might be interested in [Universal Transverse Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) which is close to what you want to do but it will require you to engage with some of the mathematics of map projections.  I see no way around this.

I exclude from consideration that you would be satisfied with 'squares' of equal angular measure, I mean (for example) something like 'squares' of 2 degrees of lat or long on each side.  The maths for that would be trivial and you wouldn't have asked here on SO for guidance.

Comment: This is also plain wrong.  It's not looking for a projection.

Comment: Hey. nothing is so trivial that's not worth to ask for or to explain to others. Maybe you cool down a bit and explain what you mean?